Do Smooth Quotient Maps on Manifolds Always Locally Resemble Projections?
I'm investigating the relationship between smooth submersions and smooth quotient maps in the context of smooth manifolds, and I'm particularly interested in understanding if every smooth quotient map behaves locally like a projection map, similar to smooth submersions.
Definitions and Context

Smooth Submersion: A map $ f: M \to N $ is a smooth submersion if the differential $ df_p: T_p M \to T_{f(p)} N $ is surjective for all $ p \in M $.
Smooth Quotient Map: A map $ q: M \to N $ is a smooth quotient map if it:

Is surjective.
Satisfies the quotient topology condition (i.e., a subset $ U \subseteq N $ is open if and only if $ q^{-1}(U) $ is open in $ M $).
Is smooth as a map between smooth manifolds.



Question
Smooth submersions locally resemble projections (as one of the users pointed out in comments to see  Proposition 4.28 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds). My question is:

Does every smooth quotient map also locally resemble a projection map, in a similar way to smooth submersions?

My Thoughts and Examples Explored

Circle Example: The map $ q: \mathbb{R} \to S^1 $ defined by $ q(x) = e^{2 \pi i x} $ is a smooth quotient map, but it’s unclear if it locally behaves like a projection. It wraps $ \mathbb{R} $ onto $ S^1 $ in a way that resembles covering map behavior, rather than a straightforward projection.

Identity Map $ \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to S^1 $: While this map is a homeomorphism, it’s not a diffeomorphism because the smooth structures differ (the smooth structure on $ \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} $ comes from $ \mathbb{R} $, which is not compatible with $ S^1 $ as a smooth manifold). This example has made me question when local projection behavior should or shouldn’t be expected.


I’m looking for insights or examples that clarify whether the local projection behavior applies to all smooth quotient maps. Any guidance on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

See Proposition 4.28 in Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds." Also, please ask one question at a time.

Submersions locally must look like (smooth) projections. Must every quotient map? By the way, you should include some discussion of your analysis and conclusions and we can then comment on those, rather than having to write a dissertation for you in the first place.

@TedShifrin My apologies! Thanks for pointing out!

@TedShifrin However,I have edited my question now.Please have a look.

@BenSteffan Yes,you are right!Thanks for pointing this out.I'll take care from next time onwards.

"(the smooth structure on R/Z comes from R, which is not compatible with S^1 as a smooth manifold)." this is patently false, it's a diffeomorphism.

Consider the simple example $f\colon\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, $f(z)=z^2$. Since non-constant holomorphic maps $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ are open, this is a (smooth) quotient map. But it fails to be a submersion.
